# How does the quick-start adventure for Dragonfire employ scenes?

Tags: dragonfire

In the quick-start adventure that is included with Dragonfire, encounters are drawn after every round. Does the quick-start adventure not use scenes? Or is every round its own scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [quick-start Adventure](https://dragonfirethegame.com/downloads/Dragonfire_Quick_Start_Rules.pdf) doesn't use scenes, instead  it simplifies the rules down to essentially just the Encounters phase, and player turns.